# Convert in JavaScript C# code that reads from web.config

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config

in the web.config file of my ASP.NET MVC application I have some constant string values.
sommething like this:

```
<add key="filters" value="AA;BB;CC;DD" />
```

In a C# file I create a List in this way:

```
List<string> filters = new List<string>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["filter"].Split(new char[] { ';' }));
```

Now I have to put this code in a JavaScript file
and create as many string variables as strings are present in this List.

For example, in this case I should obtain:

filterAA
filterBB
filterCC
filterDD

How can I accomplish this task?

Thank you in advance.

Luis

Comment: What's the problem? What have your tried? What doesn't work? And *"put this code in a JavaScript file"* are we talking nodejs or browser?

Comment: A simple JavaScript file in the Script folder of the web application (MVC 4).

Comment: So the browser !? Let's think this through. Do you think it would be a good idea if everyone that visits your page could read your web.config containing stuff like your database-config? Either write these configs into a `<script>` tag as [Serge shows you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542320/6567275), or create an API endpoint that returns the required data as json and access that in your script.

Comment: And reading from a TXT file? So I can modify only this txt adding values when I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can add  List to a view model in a controller, then you sent the data to View via ViewModel. Add this code inside of View

```
@model ViewModel

... your html code

<script>

   var filters = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model.Filters));
 
 </script>
```